# Convert string into valid json in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following string:

```
{"data.childData1":"s1","data.childData2":"s2",...}
```

How do I convert it to:

```
{"data":{
     "childData1":"s1",
      "childData2":"s2"
   }
}
```

Comment: What you need is formatted JSON, not valid json. Both of them are valid examples of JSON. *plus, I am not sure about the extra set of `{}` in your second sample*

Comment: How do I format it with JSON.net

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this lib](http://www.markdavidrogers.com/oxitesample/Blog/json-pretty-printerbeautifier-library-for-net) to beautify json, or use Json.NET ([example source](http://codebork.com/2011/08/17/pretty-printing-json-jsonnet.html)):

```
public string GetPrettyPrintedJson(string json)
{
    dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Comment: The result is still the same. No change.

Comment: Ohhhh I misunderstood your question. What you want to do is not standard, you will probably have to implement it yourself.